# How to export Animated SVG file from Adobe After Effects?

Tags: svg, animation, adobe-after-effects

I am working on a text animation in **Adobe After Effects** and I want to **export** my animation as an **Animated SVG** so that I can use it on my website and Mobile Apps.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: After effects does not have any facilities to do this. That does not mean it cannot be donr by a custom exporter.

Comment: I have been using bodymovin and theres no exporting on svg file

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the [Bodymovin plugin](https://github.com/bodymovin/bodymovin)?

It's a hacky little extension of After Effects that allows you to export any composition you want to SVG. Works for us!

Comment: Hey there Apex! Welcome to GD.SE! Can you edit your answer to include a little bit about that plugin and how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have any native exporting capabilities. But you could always use [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/)

Old fashioned way: you could make a loop-once gif image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Lottie library [here](http://airbnb.io/lottie/#/) currently maintained by Airbnb.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the [Lottie](http://airbnb.io/lottie/) extension for AEFX
2. Setup a comp
3. Open the Lottie extension and render your comp
4. Go to Preview in the Lottie extension window and select your render
5. Seek through the animation and Take Snapshot of the frames you want to save
6. The exported snapshots are in SVG!

Voila!